# Post complex model angularjs to web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, api

Let's say I have this models

```
public class HouseHolds
{
    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public List<HouseHoldBeneficiaries> HouseHoldBeneficiaries { get; set; }
}

public class HouseHoldBeneficiaries
{
    public Guid HouseHoldId { get; set; }
    public Guid BeneficiaryId { get; set; }
    public int HouseHoldRelationShipId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to post new HouseHold to database so I send the result from angularjs
but I Can't bind List HouseHoldBeneficiaries.

Object

```
Code: "wer"
HouseHoldBeneficiaries:
HouseHoldRelationShipId: 2
BeneficiaryId: EAFC7940-5FAD-4C04-BC01-6D052BA5E711
```

But my HouseHoldBeneficiaries is always null in the model ??

Comment: you should post your angular call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HouseHoldBeneficiaries` is a collection and thus needs to be send as json array like

```
{
Code:"wer",
HouseHoldBeneficiaries: [
{
 HouseHoldRelationShipId: 2,
 BeneficiaryId: EAFC7940-5FAD-4C04-BC01-6D052BA5E711
}
]
}
```

Comment: Exactly, it was send like object not array. it solves my problem, thanks